# Displaying a sharepoint page in another page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I want to display a wiki page in a frame of not wiki page. I do it as `iframe` using

```
output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Iframe).
```

It displays a page but with navigation and menu of a site. How can I display a "pure" page?

Answer (score 2):

On SharePoint 2010, try to append the ?IsDlg=1 to your page URL. It should get rid of the navigation and menu. This is what SharePoint uses to render modal dialogs.